# Query to return user tags along with usage count

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I've been trying to find this on the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=featured&pagesize=100), but no luck. I need some help to write a query identical to the one found on our profile pages that displays tag information. The query would have to return:

1. Each tag used by the user
2. The number of times this tag has been used.
3. The number of points gained for answers given to questions that use this tag.

[I wrote the following so far on data-explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/103079/) to get the tags and to the tag count:

```
SELECT COUNT(tags.tagName), tags.tagName
  FROM postTags
    LEFT JOIN tags ON postTags.tagId = tags.id
    LEFT JOIN posts ON postTags.postId = posts.id
  WHERE posts.ownerUserId = 3
  GROUP BY tags.tagName
```

But I'm not sure how to get the score count per answer, or item 3 in my list!

Any help would appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1085622?UserId=276959) that contains all data you asked for.

It does calculate both score and reputation.

```
;with reputation as (
select p.owneruserid
     , v.postid
     , sum(case 
           when p.communityowneddate is null
                or v.creationdate <  p.communityowneddate
           then
             case p.posttypeid
             when 1 then
               case v.votetypeid 
               when 2 then 5
               when 3 then -2
               else 0
               end
             when 2 then
               case v.votetypeid 
               when 1 then 15
               when 2 then 10
               when 3 then -2
               else 0
               end
             else 0
             end
           else 0
           end
           ) + (case when min(acceptedanswerid) is not null then 2 else 0 end) rep
from votes v
inner join posts p on p.id = v.postid
where posttypeid in (1,2)
and votetypeid in (1, 2, 3)
group by p.owneruserid
       , v.postid
)
select t.tagname
     , sum(p.score) [total score]
     , sum(case when p.communityowneddate is null then p.score else 0 end) [non-cw score]
     , sum(case 
           when p.communityowneddate is null 
           then 
           case p.posttypeid 
           when 1 then p.score else 0 end
           else 0 
           end) [non-cw question score]
     , sum(case 
           when p.communityowneddate is null 
           then 
           case p.posttypeid 
           when 2 then cast(p.score as bigint) else 0 end
           else 0 
           end) [non-cw answer score]      
     , sum (case when p.posttypeid = 1 then r.rep else 0 end) [Reputation from Questions]
     , sum (case when p.posttypeid = 2 then r.rep else 0 end) [Reputation from Answers]
     , count(distinct p.id) [total posts]
     , sum( case when p.posttypeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) [Questions]
     , sum( case when p.posttypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) [Answers]
from posts p
inner join reputation r on r.owneruserid = p.owneruserid and p.id = r.postid
inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = q.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where p.posttypeid in (1, 2) -- 1 = Q, 2 = A
and p.owneruserid = ##userid:int?578411##
group by t.tagname
order by [non-cw answer score] desc
```

When run today for your Stack Overflow account this will be the result:

[image: all score and rep per tag for a userr]

Keep in mind SEDE updates on Sunday 03:00 UTC. There is also a [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) and a [chat room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede)

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track.

I created a query that does a decent approximation:

https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/s/1479/my-tags-on-profile-page

The only difference between this and the My Tags area is that this doesn't include community-wiki post stats (they don't count towards the totals, but the number of posts is included). The query would have to be rewritten slightly to grab data from the Votes table instead (to find the non-CW votes before the post was converted). This is exact if you don't have any CW posts.

Comment: thanks. I guess adding that column goes a long way to complicate the query, huh? I'll have to spend some time playing around with it to see what I can do. I'm debating if it's even worth it at this point--unless I can find a way to do it without creating an additional table on the fly...

Comment: Doesn't work for StackOverflow: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/38002/my-tags-on-profile-page. I get the error "_String or binary data would be truncated.
 The statement has been terminated._"

Comment: @Cœur there is this line in that query `Tag nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,` where you need to replace the `25` with `35` as the allowed tag length was increased.